# Formatting a broken HDD and reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, dell, live-usb

I bought Dell Inspiron N5010 in 2011. In 2018, I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10. Since then when running Ubuntu, the PC is heating up a lot, so I've been using only Windows 10 all along, but in between I faced GRUB issues many times and fixed using fsck or set commands.

Now the machine won't start. I tried installing GRUB and reinstalling Ubuntu as well, but nothing worked. When I ran diagnostics from BIOS, then I got HDD error 2000:0146.

I will be glad if you can help me with fixing the HDD from an Ubuntu live USB. If this doesn't work, I would like to format my PC and reinstall Ubuntu. Can this be done on an HDD with errors?

Answer (score 2):

The hard drive is well past its expected life.

> HDDs wear out and fail over time, taking their data with them. **Any
> files residing on a single HDD that’s a few years old is destined to
> be lost – not ‘if’ but ‘when’**.

(Citation from [this article](https://blog.archiware.com/blog/how-long-does-a-hard-drive-last/))

My personal experience is after 5 to 7 years its a game of roulette.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point to installing Ubuntu on a failed HDD that has errors especially when SSDs are so cheap. SSDs last much longer than HDDs because as the name suggests an SSD is a **S**olid **S**tate **D**rive. If your stored data on the HDD matters to you, back it up and upgrade your storage device.